# Building Virtual Array with Choose & Specific Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've worked on this problem for about 10 hours now and can't seem to come up with a solution.

I need to come up with a formula that gives me the second smallest result from a virtual array that I create with the choose function. The problem I am having is how to go about building the array. I would use Choose({1,2},Array 1, Array 2) to build the virtual array, but I only want to add values to it that meet a certain criteria. It's best to describe with an example.. Lets say Array 1 is values A1:A10 and values B1:B10 has either an "X" or "Y". I only want to add the values from A1:A10 where values B1:B10 = "X". The same would be true with Array 2.

I'll be happy to provide further details as necessary.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen the aggregate. Will look into it! looks like it is useful here! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [AGGREGATE function¹](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can easily accomplish this for Excel 2010 and higher.

[image: AGGREGATE - second smallest with conditions]

The standard formula in D4 is,

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, A1:A10/(B1:B10="Y"), 2)
```

By forcing everything in column A that does not have a Y in column B to a `$DIV/0!` error and ignoring all errors (the 6), we can use the [SMALL sub-function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) (the 15) of AGGREGATE with a *k* of 2.

¹<sub>AGGREGATE was introduced with Excel 2010. If you have a previous version, post a comment and another solution may be possible.</sub>